# Horde with IMP authentication does not authorize mail service (imp)

Tags: nginx, horde, imp

I did a fresh install of Horde 5.2.13 on nginx 1.10.2 with PHP 7.0.15 all as shipped with current Debian Testing. Horde runs as a virtual server in its own PHP pool with its own user. It is configured to use a remote IMAP server (Dovecot) for authentication - and as mail store I hope.

Logging in into Horde works nicely with the IMAP credentials. But on the user's dashboard I see *User ___ is not authorized for Mail (client.fqdn)*. I've seen quite a few mailing list entries with similar issues, but so far none seems to fit my scenario.

Clicking on the webmail tab asks for another authentication, which fails with the IMAP credentials.

I didn't post any configuration, because it's so much and I currently have no clue where to start looking. I'm totally new to Horde. My thanks for any idea for a structured troubleshooting approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [using the Horde-Imp mailing list](https://marc.info/?l=imp&m=148659745410023&w=2). So what was it?

1st: The `hordeauth` property of the server must be set to make Horde use the login credentials also for the imap server.

2nd: The imap server used for login specified in `horde/conf.php` is not related to the imap server for imp specified in `imp/backends.local.php`. So a successful login doesn't mean anything to the mail subsystem, which ...

3rd: ... used a default local imap server from `imp/backends.php`, which simply didn't exist. Setting the `disabled` property for the default server in `imp/backends.local.php` made IMP chose the self-defined server from the same file.

And then everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Best answer as above

in debian
/etc/horde/imp/
following worked

```
$servers['imap'] = array( 

    // ENABLED by default; will connect to IMAP port on local server

    'disabled' => true,
    'name' => 'IMAP Server',
    'hostspec' => 'localhost',
    'hordeauth' => true,
    'protocol' => 'imap',
    'port' => 143,
```